# Pass Values to a query through fucntions argument in Perl

Tags: oracle, perl

I have a perl code which queries the Oracle 11G database to pull the count of the 'values' from a table.

```
$sqlStatement="SELECT count(values) FROM Table WHERE values IN ('value1','value2','value3',.... 'valuen')"
```

How can I pass the values in query through a subroutine's argument?

For example:

```
$sqlStatement="SELECT count(values) FROM Table WHERE values IN ($values)

subroutine($values)
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question and add some more code? How are you running that query? You will need to look a placeholders, though.

Comment: `local $, = ","; $sqlStatement="SELECT .. values IN (@{[ ('?') x @values ]})";` but it's pretty unclear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks.. Simbabque & Сухой27.. I have solved the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it make more sense to pass in the values using an array rather than a scalar?

```
count_values(@values);
```

Then the subroutine could start like this:

```
sub count_values {
  my @values = @_;

  my $sql = 'select count(values) from table where values in (';
  $sql .= join ',', ('?') x @values;
  $sql .= ')';

  my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute(@values);

  my $count = ($sth->fetchrow_array)[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave, it worked for me. Thank you so much... :)

Comment: If my answer was useful to you, then please consider voting it up or accepting it.